# How to find group of polygons under one union polygon in shapely

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have list of hexagon polygons that are that are colored in a specific color defining a region. I have unionised the hexagons on the basis of color. Now I need to find the groups inside those unions that are not connect with each other. Is there a way to find that?[image]

Like in this example there are 3 pink hexagon groups that are not connect and are under one union. How can I find each group individually under the same union that are not connected

Comment: Perhaps your question is actually about how to split a multipolygon into a list of polygons?

Comment: @VictorSavenije yes exactly.

Comment: polygons = list(shapely.Multipolygon.geoms)